# error: autoconf failed with exit status: 1

Tags: linux, centos7

Hi am trying to a build shell script in centos 7.5 but am stopped due to the following error

**ERROR:**

```
[root@localhost unimrcp-1.5.0]# ./bootstrap
+ libtoolize --force --automake --copy
+ aclocal -I build/acmacros
+ automake --foreign --add-missing --copy
Usage: autoconf [-h] [--help] [-m dir] [--macrodir=dir]
       [-l dir] [--localdir=dir] [--version] [template-file]
automake: error: autoconf failed with exit status: 1
+ autoconf
autoconf: configure.in: No such file or directory
+ rm -rf autom4te.cache
```

and the following is the shell script i tried to execute.
**bootstrap.sh**

```
#! /bin/sh

case `uname` in
    Darwin) libtoolize=glibtoolize ;;
    *)      libtoolize=libtoolize  ;;
esac

set -x
$libtoolize --force --automake --copy
aclocal -I build/acmacros
automake --foreign --add-missing --copy
autoconf

rm -rf autom4te.cache
```

Can any one help me to solve this problem?
Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe avoid the `bootstrap` and try `autoupdate` first. Then use `libtoolize` followed by `autoreconf`. I've found that works on most OSes, including old ones like Fedora 15 and odd ones like Solaris and AIX. Also see [this autoconf](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/TestScripts/cryptest-autotools.sh) test script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is failing at the `autoconf` step.

From `man autoconf`:

> Synopsis
>
> autoconf [OPTION]... [TEMPLATE-FILE]
>
> Description
>
> Generate a configuration script from a TEMPLATE-FILE if given, or
> 'configure.ac' if present, or else 'configure.in'. Output is sent to
> the standard output if TEMPLATE-FILE is given, else into 'configure'.

As you can see `autoconf` is either expecting a `TEMPLATE-FILE` or it is looking for `configure.ac` or `configure.in`.

Since neither is given, your script is failing.

Comment: Hi this was actually helped me thank you so much, along with that one more thing to be done is autoconf should be 2.59 or above but i was using 2.13 .